# Issue about getting a 404 error page when scraping a website

Tags: python, web-crawler

I wanted to get Fear and greed index from 'https://alternative.me/crypto/ and I found a url where the XHR data is by using Chrome network tool but when trying to **scrape** the website, I got 404 or 500 error page.

```
url = 'https://alternative.me/api/crypto/fear-and-greed-index/history'
headers = {
    'user-agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'),
    'Referer': ('https://alternative.me/crypto/fear-and-greed-index/'),
    'Accept-Language': ('ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'),
    'accept-encoding': ('gzip, deflate, br'),
    'accept': ('application/json, text/plain, */*')
}

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Why are you using a POST request?

Comment: res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

Comment: It's because the request method is POST not GET.

Comment: When using a 'requests.get', I get 404 error, and when using a post request, I get 500 error.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrapping__ and __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__) not scrapping or scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Comment: I see. Sorry for my broken English.